# Grails NoClassDefFoundError: nu/xom/Serializer

Tags: xml, json, grails

I am trying to convert JSON to XML in Grails via:

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject
import net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer
...

String convertToXmlString(jsonString) {
    JSONObject json = JSONObject.fromObject(jsonString)
    String xml = new XMLSerializer().write( json )

    return xml
}
```

but when I try to run the code I get the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nu.xom.Serializer
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:156)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:128)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I haven't run into something like this before.  Aren't I importing all of the necessary classes?  I have imported the [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/usage.html#xml) jar into my `/lib` folder, and run `grails compile --refresh-dependencies`.  Is there another step I need to run?

I'm open to other ways of converting JSON/maps -> XML/strings and back, but this issue seems like it should be easily fixed.

Comment: the problem is not the json-lib.jar but, the missing [xom-xxx.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the grails.converters to accomplish this:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.converters.XML

def o = JSON.parse("{ foo: 'bar' }") // creates a JSONObject
def x = o as XML // creates an XML
println x
def s = x as String // create the String representing the XML
println s
```

Result will be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><map><entry key="foo">bar</entry></map>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><map><entry key="foo">bar</entry></map>
```

Comment: +1 and I should have mentioned this in the question, but is there a way to use the key as the node name?  ie <foo>bar</foo>?

Comment: Check out these links, it might help you: http://jwicz.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/grails-custom-xml-marshaller/ and http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-to-convert-XML-String-or-XML-Sluper-to-grails-converters-XML-td1389203.html

Comment: I was hoping there would be a simple method call I could make, similar to xstream or json-lib.  Thanks though!